# Как открыть папку автоматически в определнном месте экрана в Windows?

Tags: windows

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Моя читцация: Я работаю на сервере который мониторит производительность всех серверов сети. При включении компьютера я хочу чтобы у меня открывалось две программы и папка с логами, где я сразу вижу какие процессы были уже произведены. Я закинул ярлыки программ и ярлык папки с логами в папку

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Вопрос: Возможно ли открыть это окно в опредленном размере и в определенном месте (справа внизу окна)? Там он в маленьком окне не будет мне мешать выполнять другие задания.